# How to concatenate a variable number of columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like:

```
    name  aka     fka
0   Alex  Al      NaN
1   Bob   Bobbert Robert
2   Carol NaN     NaN
```

I'd like to end up with a series of concatenated possible names, like:

```
0  Alex,Al
1  Bob,Bobbert,Robert
2  Carol
```

But `str.cat` will give me extra `,`s:

```
df.name.str.cat([df.aka, df.fka], sep=',', na_rep='')
0              Alex,Al,
1    Bob,Bobbert,Robert
2               Carol,,
Name: name, dtype: object
```

I could go through with a bunch of special-cased `str.replace`s to make sure there are no leading/trailing/duped `,`s, but is there a better way to join a variable number of columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
In [489]: df.apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=','), axis=1)
Out[489]:
0               Alex,Al
1    Bob,Bobbert,Robert
2                 Carol
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

For a quick fix to your `str.cat` solution, just add `str.strip(',')`:

```
df.name.str.cat([df.aka, df.fka], sep=',', na_rep='').str.strip(',')
0               Alex,Al
1    Bob,Bobbert,Robert
2                 Carol
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: This works in the example above, but not if there was a missing middle value e.g., (Bob,,Robert).

Comment: Not claiming that this would be an *eficient* way to get rid of that, but you could then chain `.str.replace(',{2,}',',')` to the end of that. @Zero's solution is clearly nicer.