# Developing a generalized logic of getting highlighted area from multiple pdfs into pandas dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pymupdf

I have created a solution using python which extracts highlighted portions from the PDF using `pymupdf` and `fitz`.

This is the code for the same.

```
def _parse_highlight(annot: fitz.Annot, wordlist: List[Tuple[float, float, float, float, str, int, int, int]]) -> str:
    points = annot.vertices
    quad_count = int(len(points) / 4)
    sentences = []
    for i in range(quad_count):
        # where the highlighted part is
        r = fitz.Quad(points[i * 4 : i * 4 + 4]).rect

        words = [w for w in wordlist if fitz.Rect(w[:4]).intersects(r)]
        sentences.append(" ".join(w[4] for w in words))
    sentence = " ".join(sentences)
    string_split = sentence.split(",")
    sent = " ".join(sorted(set(string_split), key=string_split.index))
    output = re.sub(r'\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b', r'\1,', sent)
    return output


def handle_page(page):
    wordlist = page.getText("words")  # list of words on page
    wordlist.sort(key=lambda w: (w[3], w[0]))  # ascending y, then x

    highlights = []
    annot = page.firstAnnot
    while annot:
        if annot.type[0] == 8:
            highlights.append(_parse_highlight(annot, wordlist))
        annot = annot.next
    return highlights

def main():
    filepath = [file for file in glob.glob("Folder/*.pdf")]
    for file in filepath:
        doc = fitz.open(file)
        #print(file)

        highlights = []
        for page in doc:
            highlights += handle_page(page)

        print(highlights)
```

This when run on 2 PDFs gives me a result like this:-
list1: `['Ashmore 2, 554, 1.06, Close Brothers 2, 704, 1.12,', 'Close Brothers 2, 704, 1.12]`
list2: `['HDFC Bank Ltd. 6.98, ICICI Bank Ltd. 4.82, Infosys Ltd. 4.37']`

In list1, The no of columns which was highlighted in 1PDF was 3
In list2, The no of columns which was highlighted in 2PDF was 2.

If I have to build a dataframe from this. How do I develop a logic to build a generalized one(if a pdf is having 4 columns so then in dataframe as well it should be 4)
So that the dataframe columns will be in sync with the list above?
This is how I have built the dataframe logic

```
def main():
    try:
        filepath = [file for file in glob.glob("Folder/*.pdf")]
        my_df = pd.DataFrame()
        for file in filepath:
            doc = fitz.open(file)
            #print(file)

            highlights = []
            for page in doc:
                highlights += handle_page(page)

            #print(highlights)
            for i in range(len(highlights)):
                highlights_alt = highlights[i].split(',')
                #print(highlights_alt)
                df = pd.DataFrame(highlights_alt, columns=['Security Name'])
                #print(df.columns.tolist())
                df[['Name', 'Value']] = df['Name'].str.rsplit(n=1, expand=True)
                df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
                print(df.head())
                print(df.shape)
```

This code fails/doesn't work properly if columns highlighted from pdfs are more than 2.
How do I generalize this? Please help!!

**EDIT**:
Using Laurent's code I get this output which is not expected.
This is the list that I get when I print `highlights` =

```
['DWF 1, 340, 0.84,', 'Equiniti 491, 0.31,', 'Inchcape 947, 0.59,', 'Speedy Hire 1, 054, 0.66,']
```

This is the highlights_alt I get after printing it `highlights_alt` =

```
[['D'], ['W'], ['F'], [' '], ['1'], ['', ''], [' '], ['3'], ['4'], ['0'], ['', ''], [' '], ['0'], ['.'], ['8'], ['4'], ['', '']]
[['E'], ['q'], ['u'], ['i'], ['n'], ['i'], ['t'], ['i'], [' '], ['4'], ['9'], ['1'], ['', ''], [' '], ['0'], ['.'], ['3'], ['1'], ['', '']]
[['I'], ['n'], ['c'], ['h'], ['c'], ['a'], ['p'], ['e'], [' '], ['9'], ['4'], ['7'], ['', ''], [' '], ['0'], ['.'], ['5'], ['9'], ['', '']]
[['S'], ['p'], ['e'], ['e'], ['d'], ['y'], [' '], ['H'], ['i'], ['r'], ['e'], [' '], ['1'], ['', ''], [' '], ['0'], ['5'], ['4'], ['', ''], [' '], ['0'], ['.'], ['6'], ['6'], ['', '']]
```

This is the dataframe that I get `df`=

```
Name Value_0
0    D       0
1    W       0
2    F       0
3            0
4    1       0
  Name Value_0
0    E       0
1    q       0
2    u       0
3    i       0
4    n       0
  Name Value_0
0    I       0
1    n       0
2    c       0
3    h       0
5    a       0
  Name Value_0
0    S       0
1    p       0
2    e       0
4    d       0
5    y       0
```

Comment: There are a few answers for 'Handling Variable Number of Columns with Pandas`. This one might be suitable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792881/how-to-concatenate-a-variable-number-of-columns-in-pandas

Comment: @SyKer thanks for the prompt response, however this won't help me much as the way my list is getting populated based on the no of pdfs.

Answer (score 1):

So, given the following random records:

```py
highlights = [
    ["HDFC Bank Ltd., 6.98", "ICICI Bank Ltd., 4.82", "Infosys Ltd., 4.37"],
    [
        "Ashmore 2, 554, 1.06",
        "Close Brothers 2, 704, 1.12",
        "Close Brothers 2, 704, 1.12",
    ],
    [
        "HDFC Bank Ltd., 6.98, 7.99, 8.22",
        "ICICI Bank Ltd., 4.82, 5.45, 6.89",
        "Infosys Ltd., 4.37, 1.56, 3.58",
        "Close Brothers 2, 704, 1.12, 9.42, 3.47",
        "Ashmore 2, 554, 1.06, 5.14, 6.77",
    ],
    [
        "DWF 1, 340, 0.84,",
        "Equiniti 491, 0.31,",
        "Inchcape 947, 0.59,",
        "Speedy Hire 1, 054, 0.66,",
    ],
]
```

With the help of Python standard libray [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-contents), you could do this to manage any number of columns:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

highlights_alt = [
    [
        re.sub(
            pattern=r"(.*)(\s)(\d)(\W\s)(\d.*)",
            repl=r"\g<1>, \g<3>\g<5>",
            string=record,
        ).split(",")
        for record in item
    ]
    for item in highlights
]

for item in highlights_alt:
    df = pd.DataFrame(item).fillna(0).drop_duplicates(keep="first", inplace=False)
    df.columns = ["Name"] + [f"Value_{n}" for n in range(df.shape[1] - 1)]
    df = (
        df.replace("", np.nan)
        .replace(0, np.nan)
        .dropna(axis=1, how="all")
        .replace(np.nan, 0)
    )
    print(df.head())
```

Which outputs:

```py
              Name Value_0
0   HDFC Bank Ltd.    6.98
1  ICICI Bank Ltd.    4.82
2     Infosys Ltd.    4.37
             Name Value_0 Value_1
0         Ashmore    2554    1.06
1  Close Brothers    2704    1.12
              Name Value_0 Value_1 Value_2 Value_3
0   HDFC Bank Ltd.    6.98    7.99    8.22       0
1  ICICI Bank Ltd.    4.82    5.45    6.89       0
2     Infosys Ltd.    4.37    1.56    3.58       0
3   Close Brothers    2704    1.12    9.42    3.47
4          Ashmore    2554    1.06    5.14    6.77
           Name Value_0 Value_1
0           DWF    1340    0.84
1  Equiniti 491    0.31       0
2  Inchcape 947    0.59       0
3   Speedy Hire    1054    0.66
```

Comment: Hi Laurent, Thanks for the thoughtful answer, I have a doubt however. In the last dataframe under Name column the records are 'Close Brothers 2' and 'Ashmore 2'. It should be 'Close Brothers' and 'Ashmore'. The digits in that case should go to Value_0 column thereby making the values as 2704 and 2554 respectively.

Comment: I checked it, for the value 2,704 in the dataframe it is showing 2.704.. Same for 2,554 as well

Comment: Thanks alot for your help! will definitely try this out and let you know.

Comment: I am facing issues with respect to your code. I am editing my question after printing highlights, highlights_alt and df. Let me know how can it be fixed.

Comment: I have updated my answer with this new data and refactored the code in a more pythonic way. The output is as expected. Not much more I can do here, if this answer has solved your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. Cheers.